# Using rx.js, how do I emit a memoized result from an existing observable sequence on a timer?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm currently teaching myself reactive programming with rxjs, and I've set myself a challenge of creating an observable stream which will always emit the same result to a subscriber no matter what.

I've memoized the creation of an HTTP "GET" stream given a specific URL, and I'm trying to act on that stream every two seconds, with the outcome being that for each tick of the timer, I'll extract a cached/memoized HTTP result from the original stream.

```
import superagent from 'superagent';
import _ from 'lodash';

// Cached GET function, returning a stream that emits the HTTP response object
var httpget = _.memoize(function(url) {
  var req = superagent.get(url);
  req = req.end.bind(req);
  return Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(req)();
});

// Assume this is created externally and I only have access to response$
var response$ = httpget('/ontologies/acl.ttl');

// Every two seconds, emit the memoized HTTP response
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 2000)
  .map(() => response$)
  .flatMap($ => $)
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log('Got the response!');
  });
```

I was sure that I'd have to stick a call to `replay()` in there somewhere, but no matter what I do, a fresh HTTP call is initiated every two seconds. How can I structure this so that I can construct an observable from a URL and have it always emit the same HTTP result to any subsequent subscribers?

**EDIT**
I found a way to get the result I want, but I feel like I am missing something, and should be able to refactor this with a much more streamlined approach:

```
var httpget = _.memoize(function(url) {
  var subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
  try {
    superagent.get(url).end((err, res) => {
      if(err) {
        subject.onError(err);
      }
      else {
        subject.onNext(res);
        subject.onCompleted();
      }
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    subject.onError(e);
  }
  return subject.asObservable();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code sample is actually closer to the way to do it

```
var httpget = _.memoize(function(url) {
  var req = superagent.get(url);
  return Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(req.end, req)();
});
```

However, this isn't working because there appears to be a bug in `fromNodeCallback`. As to work around till this is fixed, I think you are actually looking for the `AsyncSubject` instead of `ReplaySubject`. The latter works, but the former is designed for exactly this scenario (and doesn't have the overhead of an array creation + runtime checks for cache expiration if that matters to you).

```
var httpget = _.memoize(function(url) {

  var subject = new Rx.AsyncSubject();
  var req = superagent.get(url);
  Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback(req.end, req)().subscribe(subject);
  return subject.asObservable();

});
```

Finally, though `map` appreciates that you are thinking of it, you can simplify your `timer` code by using the `flatMap` overload that takes an `Observable` directly:

```
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 2000)
  .flatMap($response)
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log('Got the response');
  });
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that was frustrating the heck out of me, and certainly wasn't the behaviour I'd assumed I should expect from `fromNodeCallback`. I see you've submitted a bug for it, so maybe it'll get fixed soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NathanRidley, it should be fixed now.

Comment: This question was raised a while ago, but I am wondering why you need `_.memoize` if using `AsyncSubject`?

Comment: @eric99 each call would be specific to a url, so if the caller did `httpget('foo')` that would return the underlying `AsyncSubject` which would be different from `httpget('bar')`. Since `memoize` caches by the first parameter it would remove the need to do caching yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am getting your question wrong, `Observable.combineLatest` does just that for you, it cache the last emitted value of your observable.

This code sends the request once and then give same cached response every 200 ms:

```
import reqPromise from 'request-promise';
import {Observable} from 'rx';

let httpGet_ = (url) =>
      Observable
      .combineLatest(
        Observable.interval(200),
        reqPromise(url),
        (count, response) => response
      );

httpGet_('http://google.com/')
  .subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    e => console.error(e)
  );
```

Comment: `combineLatest` is for tracking state across multiple streams. That's fine, but it's not really what I was looking for here; I wanted a way to emit the original callback result no matter who subscribes in the future.